# employee scheduling

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I have $20$ employees, I am trying to figure out a schedule of how to work them in to a 
$6$ on $3$ off
or
$5$ on $3$ off
or
$4$ on $2$ off
schedule

(a)on=working (b)off=days off I am trying to figure out what the best ratio of days working to days off will maximize the number of employees I have avaliable for work on any given day.

Comment: Without additional information, I'm not sure how to answer this question. First, can you be *very* specific about what "$a$ on $b$ off" means? Second, are you trying to also minimize the number of employees working at one given time? It seems that some other constraint is going to be necessary to provide a more useful schedule. Maybe if you clear up the stuff that's already here, that constraint will appear more naturally.

Comment: (a)on=working (b)off=days off I am trying to figure out what the best ratio of days working to days off will maximize the number of employees I have avaliable for work on any given day.

Answer (score 1):

The simple answer is 6 on 3 off gives you $\frac 23$ working, while 5 on 3 off gives $\frac 58$ working, clearly worse.  4 on 2 off is like 6 on 3 off in that people work $\frac 23$ of the days.  With 20 employees, spread them evenly and you will have 12 or 13 available each day, maybe 14 with overlap.  Just fill out a schedule in a spreadsheet and see what works.

Answer (score 0):

If you do $1$ on $0$ off then all $20$ workers will be available every day, at least until they all go out on strike. Presumably there are some constraints you are not sharing with us.